# How to fix dragging element out of context issue while dragging using jQuery.UI

Tags: jquery-ui

I have added a task on calendar, where a task may take 3 hours to complete on Monday but the same task may take 5 hours or more or less to complete the same task.

1. Problem when I drag the task over the day and when the 50% or more area of dragging element goes out side the calendar border then drop: event of .droppable() is not working and draggable element revert back to previous place.
2. ui-dragging-hover event is not adding while moving 50% or more area out side the calendare.

Note:- Point 1) and 2) both are related if point 2.) will work the point 1.) will work

[image]

Comment: If you create a fiddle demonstrating the basic issue here we can try to resolve.  Short of someone already knowing the answer, we simple don't have the time to create the appp to this point to begin the troubleshoting.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example